# Is there a threshold to asking questions to seed questions?

Tags: discussion, seeding-questions

After reading this [meta thread about seeding questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10100/should-we-intentionally-seed-questions-for-new-games) I decided to ask a few questions that were roaming in my mind for a few days... and I felt bad for asking them all at once when they were answered pretty much at the same time.

Shoud I feel ashamed? Because I feel a little bit ashamed about it.

I feel like I'm farming reputation points when asking a bunch of questions at once, while I was genuinely curious about the answers.

Here are the related questions I posted (which I feel are valid questions for the site too):

[Is there any disadvantage/risk when using a software licensed to someone else?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/195029/is-there-any-disadvantage-risk-when-using-a-software-licensed-to-someone-else)
[What are the ways to obtain higher version of a software?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/195022/what-are-the-ways-to-obtain-higher-version-of-a-software)
[How does skull amount affect the Golem's strength and HP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194949/how-much-does-skull-amount-affects-golems-strenght-and-hp)
[How does neutral minions HP and damage scale throughout the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194948/how-does-neutral-minions-hp-and-damage-scale-throughout-the-game)

Comment: Related: [Is there a question limit?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7245/4797)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Ask valid questions as you think of them. Good questions are never unwanted.

There is a system-enforced rate limit on how fast you ask questions. Although I don't remember what it is off the top of my head, it's only going to matter if you go really crazy, so I wouldn't really worry about that either.

Just make sure they're good questions, and you're good to go.

Comment: For users <125 rep, you can ask a question once every 20 minutes. For users <10k rep, a captcha is tripped if two questions are asked within 60 seconds. For users >10k rep, a captcha is tripped if two questions are asked within 30 seconds. [Source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/214193)